# Compare Credentials to his one's own login credentials

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, javascript, credentials

I would like to compare the current user credentials with my UserAccount and if they are identical then I would like to have an alert, but It doesn't work. I don't know why.I hoept that you can help me.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");  
var context = null;  
var web = null;  
var currentUser = null;  
function getWebUserData() {  
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    web = context.get_web();  
    currentUser = web.get_currentUser();  
    currentUser.retrieve();  
    context.load(web);  
    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));  
}  
function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {  
    var userObject = web.get_currentUser();
    alert(userObject.get_loginName());
    textbox1.value=userObject.get_title();
     var name= userObject.get_loginName().toString();
     if(name=='Domain\J.Doe'){
     alert('works');
     }
     else{
     alert
     ('it doesn't work');
     }

    alert('User name: ' + userObject.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + userObject.get_loginName());  
}  
function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {  
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
}
```

Best Regards

Matthias

Comment: In SharePoint Online, the entire identity claims is returned for the login name.  So perhaps trying comparing against `i:0#.w|Domain\J.Doe`?  Then again, I see your alert prior to the if statement, so if that were the case, you'd already know.

Answer (score 0):

no need to load the whole web object when you are already getting the user object from the web... you just need to load it into the context when its retrived sucessfully!

try

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWebUserData, "sp.js");  
var context = null;  
var web = null;  
var currentUser = null;  

function getWebUserData()
{  
    this.context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    this.web = context.get_web();  
    this.currentUser = web.get_currentUser();  
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);  
    this.context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));  
}  


function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) 
{  
     textbox1.value = currentUser.get_title();

     if(currentUser.get_loginName() == 'Domain\J.Doe')
     {
         alert('works');
     }
     else
     {
         alert('it doesn't work');
     }

    alert('User name: ' + currentUser.get_title() + '\n Login Name:' + currentUser.get_loginName());  
}  

function onFailureMethod(sender, args) 
{  
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace()); 
}
```